# WPF: Bind Canvas.Top and Panel.ZIndex programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, binding

How can I bind the `Canvas.Top` and `Panel.ZIndex` property of an object only via code in C#? I want to obtain that the lower an element is, the higher its `ZIndex` is. I'm somewhat new to WPF, so I can't figure out well how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Binding as shown below. The parantheses in the `Path` string are necessary because the source property is an attached property.

```
element.SetBinding(Panel.ZIndexProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self,
        Path = new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)")
    });
```

You could also directly pass the source DependencyProperty to the PropertyPath constructor like this:

```
element.SetBinding(Panel.ZIndexProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self,
        Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty)
    });
```

Conversion from `double` to `int` is done implicitly by the framework. However, if you need some "scaling" factor, you would also have to add a Binding Converter.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!  What I was missing was the new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    <Canvas>
        <Border Panel.ZIndex="{Binding Location, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToIntConverter}}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Location}"/>
    </Canvas>
```

DoubleToIntConverter is a converter that takes a Double and returns an int.
Location is a Double stored in your ViewModel.

Comment: I need it in pure C#, not xaml :\